# Infinite Monkey Theorem; why does the percentage stay at zero?

Tags: python, python-2.7, floating-point, output, percentage

A challenge from a book I'm following instructed me to write a program that will (eventually) randomly generate a snippet of one of Shakespeare's sonnets.
The program runs without crashing, however, I noticed that the percentage printout in the main() function stays at zero, even thought I'm using float() to make it divide properly in Python 2.

```
import random

def generate_one(strlen):
    """Generates random string of characters"""
    chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    rand_list = []
    for i in range(strlen):
        rand_list.append(chars[random.randrange(len(chars))])
    rand_string = ''.join(rand_list)
    return rand_string


def test_string(test_string, answer, check):
    """Puts correctly guessed words into check_list"""
    for word in answer.split():
        if word in test_string.split() and word not in check:
            check[answer.split().index(word)] = word


def main():
    """Main program loop"""
    loop_iterations = 0
    snippet = "methinks it is like a weasel"
    check_list = []
    for i in range(len(snippet.split())):
        check_list.append("***") 
    same_words = 0
    for i in snippet.split():
        if i in check_list:
            same_words += 1
    while snippet != ' '.join(check_list):
        test_word = generate_one(len(snippet))
        test_string(test_word, snippet, check_list)
        loop_iterations += 1
        if loop_iterations % 100000 == 0:
            # the percentage stays at zero, why?
            print "Percentage: ", float(same_words) / len(snippet.split())
            print ' '.join(check_list)


main()
```

And here is a sample of the output:

```
Percentage:  0.0
*** it is *** a ***
Percentage:  0.0
*** it is *** a ***
Percentage:  0.0
*** it is *** a ***
Percentage:  0.0
*** it is *** a ***
Percentage:  0.0
*** it is *** a ***
```

As you can see, the program quickly generates and stores the three smaller words, which should make the percentage above zero.

So why is the percentage staying at zero? What have I missed?

Comment: Check out http://pythontutor.com

Comment: @Dani I checked it out; great material. It's just what I need to get over the newbie learning curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop which increments `same_words` is outside of your main while loop, meaning that both `same_words` and your percentage output will never be anything but 0.  You need to add code to increment it for each match. One possible way would be to modify `test_string` to return the number of matches

```
def test_string(test_string, answer, check):
    """Puts correctly guessed words into check_list"""
    matches = 0
    for word in answer.split():
        if word in test_string.split() and word not in check:
            check[answer.split().index(word)] = word
            matches += 1

    return matches
```

And then change the loop to

```
while snippet != ' '.join(check_list):
    test_word = generate_one(len(snippet))
    same_words += test_string(test_word, snippet, check_list)
    loop_iterations += 1
    if loop_iterations % 100000 == 0:
        print "Percentage: ", float(same_words) / len(snippet.split())
        print ' '.join(check_list)
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that; it seems so obvious to me now.